# GAE datastore settings for non-database applications

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an application on GAE which does **not** use any database features, nor do I plan to do so in the future. In *Application Settings* it says *Master/Slave Replication Deprecated!*.

My question: Should I still migrate my application to *High Replication Datastore* for some reason or doesn’t it make any difference?

One thought: What if the database server connected to my application is down? Will my application be stopped too, if it’s not HRD? There might be other issues/considerations, too.

Another thought: It sounds like the [SLA](https://developers.google.com/appengine/sla) is only available for HRD-applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely upgrade anyway.

Not only will you get the SLA that's only for HRD, you will also have your app served from the newer datacenters.  Plus, even if you aren't directly using the datastore, if you are using sessions or task queues, those services use datastore internally to store state for you.

Also, I noticed an improvement on memcache performance after upgrading... So, yes.  Do the upgrade, the M/S datastore is deprecated because the HRD infrastructure is built on newer, better technology.